# How do I change the background of a DIV after uploading an image?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, upload

Right now I have a placeholder image set as a background with an invisible asp:FileUpload overtop of it. Once the user clicks and selects an image, I want to change the placeholder image (which is set using css backgrounds).

```
<div id="icon">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="AvatarUpload" CssClass="avatar-upload" runat="server" size="38" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#icon {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background: url("../image/mobile/upload-avatar.png") no-repeat bottom center;
    background-size: 120px 120px;
}

.avatar-upload {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Is there a way to do this without having a submit/upload button?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need :

```js
    var icon = document.querySelector('#icon');
    document.querySelector('#AvatarUpload').addEventListener("change",function(e){        
       icon.style.background = 'url('+URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])+')';
    });
```

```css
#icon{
  width : 120px;
  height : 120px;
  background : red;
  background-size: contain ! important;
  overflow : hidden;
 }

#AvatarUpload{
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="icon">
  <input type="file" id="AvatarUpload"/>
</div>
```